# How to convert a "raw" string into a normal string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, rawstring

In Python, I have a string like this:

```
'\\x89\\n'
```

How can I decode it into a normal string like:

```
'\x89\n'
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If your input value is a `str` string, use `codecs.decode()` to convert:

```
import codecs

codecs.decode(raw_unicode_string, 'unicode_escape')
```

If your input value is a `bytes` object, you can use the [`bytes.decode()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
raw_byte_string.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode('\\x89\\n', 'unicode_escape')
'\x89\n'
>>> b'\\x89\\n'.decode('unicode_escape')
'\x89\n'
```

Python 2 byte strings can be decoded with the `'string_escape'` codec:

```
>>> import sys; sys.version_info[:2]
(2, 7)
>>> '\\x89\\n'.decode('string_escape')
'\x89\n'
```

For *Unicode* literals (with a `u` prefix, e.g. `u'\\x89\\n'`), use `'unicode_escape'`.

Comment: This doesn't work in python3. (`str` doesn't have a `decode` method and also `string_escape` isn't a valid encoding anymore).

Comment: @Bakuriu: The OP *never specified a Python version*.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, what I was trying to decode is a bytes class object, not a str object!

Comment: @user486005: that was crucial information; I had to assume you were using Python 2 (still the more likely option, statistically speaking). I've updated my answer to include the correct methods to use in Python 3.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't know that python-3 has remove the decode method of string object then, at first I thought it was a string object while it was a bytes object indeed, so it just happens to run successfully. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm using python3. I have a variable that I get by reference. When I try to do the conversion of my variable it doesn't work. Any ideas? Example: 

my_string = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe'
codecs.decode(my_string, 'unicode_escape')
# 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_202\x08in\\java.exe'

Comment: @grand: you don't have any escapes in that string. Echoing a string with backslashes always shows valid, copyable Python syntax. See [Why do backslashes appear twice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/24085680)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I am trying same thing in python3. seems decode function is not available with str. how do we convert raw strings to normal strings in latest python3?

Comment: name = "sandeep\tnagendra\n"
print(name) --> this gives tab and newline
print("%r" % name) --> THis converts normal string to raw string
name = r"sandeep\tnagendr\n"  
print(name) --> This prints raw string
Now how do we change raw string back to normal one?

Comment: @sandeepnagendra please read the whole answer, there is a Python 3 section. Your first expression produces a string *representation* (what `repr()` returns), which includes quotes.

Answer (score 12):

This would work for Python 3:

```
b'\\x89\\n'.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: @user486005: I am glad it helped. It was meant as addition to the Martinj Python 2 solution.