# Raw strings and repr() are equivalent?

Tags: python, string, escaping, repr

In Python, you can define a literal string as a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). Surfing on internet, I read that it is equivalent to `repr()`. More exactly, I tested that:

```py
r"mystring" == repr("mystring")[1:-1]
```

Is this always true?

EDIT: the linked question does not answer my question, since it's about difference between raw strings and unicode strings, not raw strings and `repr()`.

Comment: No its not, for example `r"\u9000mystring" == repr("\u9000mystring")[1:-1]` evaluates to `False`

Comment: So I suppose the correct way to convert a raw string to an escaped string is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242433/how-to-convert-a-raw-string-into-a-normal-string)

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a "raw string", there are only raw string **literals**. The "conversion" you speak of is *interpreting the text* by replacing some text sequences with other text sequences. You cannot unambiguously "convert to an escaped string" because there are multiple possible "escaped" versions of any given input.