# How to format a string with escape sequences implemented? Not same as earlier Q

Tags: python

I have an output coming out of a function. The output string has escape sequence (mainly \n).

I need to format this string so that escape sequence are implemented before I pass the formatted string to another function. The second function needs it in formatted way for it to do a text search with similar text.

Here's what I mean:

```
text = r'Your team should include the following \nboard-certified experts:\n \nA pulmonologist is a doctor who's an \nexpert of lung diseases.\n'

formatted_text = """Your team should include the following 
board-certified experts:
 
A pulmonologist is a doctor who's an 
expert of lung diseases."""
```

So as u see, if I do print(text), i will get the second string as print will implement the escape sequences. But I don't want to print. I want to format as second and store it another variable.

EDIT:

Pls run it in a notebook cell and DO NOT print(formatted_text). Run it just as a variable. If it doesn't remove escape sequence, it's not what I want.

[image]

Edit 2:

What I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: What kind of function returns literal escape sequences? If it's returning JSON, use `json.loads()`.

Comment: it's basically a Document variable that has the above string as part of its dictionary.

Comment: I added already in question above

Comment: Your `search_text` doesn't have literal `\n` in it. You need to use a raw string or write `\\n` to get that.

Comment: All I am saying is, I have a text string which looks like search_text. I don't want to have \n mentioned there but I want a formatted string variable which has the \n implemented as new line. So anything after \n in search_text is in a new line in that formatted variable

Comment: doesn't work. Pls run it in notebook and u will see

Comment: Is `\n \n` intentional (with space in between), or should it be `\n\n`?

Comment: Maybe it's an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Why don't you just try to modify your "search function" to make it work with a normal Python string implement

Comment: problem is I get an output in search_text format. I am trying to compare or do string match that output with a text which is in formatted_string format. if I just use it as it is, it won't compare because my search_text has \n and other escape sequences. While the text I am comparing it to has those in new lines and other things. 

I can not modify the output of both the search_text and the string I am comparing it to, without I run some logic on one of them to make them comparable. The output I get from search_text is not coming from my fnx but a package which throws that output

Comment: Also, please provide the code **as text not as screenshots**

Comment: Just use .replace(r"\n","\n") like [this](https://ideone.com/TVRph3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you are wishing to keep these escape characters function (tab, newline, etc.) but remove the actual text for it, use codecs.

```py
import codecs

text = r"Your team should include the following \nboard-certified experts:\n \nA pulmonologist is a doctor who's an \nexpert of lung diseases.\n"

print(text)

formatted_text = codecs.decode(text, 'unicode_escape')

print(formatted_text)
```

Returns:

```
Your team should include the following
board-certified experts:

A pulmonologist is a doctor who's an
expert of lung diseases.
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242433/how-to-convert-a-raw-string-into-a-normal-string) with a similar question

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT 2:
Note there is a newline character at the end of the raw string, so either remove the newline character at the end of a string OR your desired string will be slightly different.

```py
import codecs

text = r"Your team should include the following \nboard-certified experts:\n \nA pulmonologist is a doctor who's an \nexpert of lung diseases.\n" # <- because of newline here in original text

desired_text = """Your team should include the following 
board-certified experts:
 
A pulmonologist is a doctor who's an 
expert of lung diseases.
"""    # <- additional newline here

formatted_text = codecs.decode(text, 'unicode_escape')

if desired_text == formatted_text:
    print("yep, the same")
else:
    print("nope")
```

ran this with the additional newline and it works

if you need to remove any additional newlines/escape characters at the end, I would simply add this after you get the raw text and before you decode the text:

```py
# list of escape characters you want to exclude at the end
avoided_trailing_characters = ['\\s', '\\n', '\\t']

for trailing_character in avoided_trailing_characters:
    text = text.strip(trailing_character)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: codecs doesn't work. Again pls DON'T PRINT (formatted_text)

Comment: pls do not close this question if ur answer isn't correct.

Comment: Why doesn't codecs work for you?

Comment: pls check my screenshot in ur answer as EDIT

Comment: @Baktaawar I may be daft but I'm not seeing it. Is it because of the quotes around the string when you call formatted_text? That's because the print excludes the quotes and when you call formatted_text it includes the quotes as a part of the datatype. But if that's the case, that won't have an impact on your search function. Both are strings

Comment: check the edit with what I am looking for. Hope that helps. if u check formatted_text in first edit, urs has \n as part of it. I don't want \n as part of string but as implemented

Comment: @Baktaawar okay, i see what you're saying. i got it to work. it was a matter of in the raw text, there was a newline character at the end,  which would be different than your desired text. Do you want to ignore escape characters after the last non-escape character? check the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can process your text as follows:

```py
text = "Your team should include the following \\nboard-certified experts:\\n \\nA pulmonologist is a doctor who's an \\nexpert of lung diseases.\\n"


def process(text):
    return text.replace("\\n", "\n")


formatted_text = process(text)
print(formatted_text)
```

Comment: `\n` is not the only possible escape sequence.

Comment: They said "mainly", not only.

Comment: this doesn't work. I have tried it. And yes \n might not be the only escape sequence. Don't use print as print will automatically implement escape sequence so what u see is not what the variable has . U can check it if u run it in a cell of notebook and just do formatted_text and run it

Comment: @Baktaawar Stop saying that. `print()` doesn't know anything about escape sequences. Try `print(r'\n')` and you'll see.

Comment: @Baktaawar This does work for `\n`: https://ideone.com/FDyHBk

Comment: sir u r printing it

Comment: here's a simple request and exercise for all who keep saying it works by printing the variable. 

Just use ur formatted_text variable u get after running ur logic and compare it with the formatted_variable I have mentioned in my above question. If it doesn't match in simple string match, then it isn't the same.